# Pandas Drop Boolean value

Tags: python, pandas, function, boolean

Hi everyone (I am new to python)

We are given a file.tsv and we need to built a function. One of them is to drop each rows if a column (here called 'low_confidence_variant') = True. I am somehow struggling for this part. Also, any recommendation for optimizing? With the result we then need to make a miami graph. Here is what I made so far. Any tips will be usefull;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_file(file, chromosome):
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', usecols=['chromosome', 'position', 'pval', 'low_confidence_variant'])
df.drop(['low_confidence_variant'], True)
df.dropna()
sub_data = df.replace({'pval': 0}, 1e-274)
sub_data['log10'] = -np.log10(sub_data['pval'])
chr_group = sub_data.groupby(['chromosome'])
chromosome = chr_group.get_group(chromosome)
return chromosome


df1 = read_file('vitamin_d.females.tsv.gz', 1)
df2 = read_file('vitamin_d.males.tsv.gz', 1)
xa = df2['position']
ya = df2['log10']
xb = df1['position']
yb = df1['log10'] * -1
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(12, 4))
ax1.scatter(xa, ya, s=1, c="tab:blue")
ax1.set_ylabel('males $\it{-log_{10}(pval)}$')
ax1.set_title('vitamin D (nmol/L)', fontweight='bold')
ax1.axhline(-np.log10(5*10**-8), c ='darkgray', ls='--')
ax2.scatter(xb, yb, s=1, c="tab:blue")
ax2.set_ylabel('females $\it{log_{10}(pval)}$')
ax2.axhline(np.log10(5*10**-8), c ='darkgray', ls='--')
plt.xlabel('Chromosome 1 positions')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
plt.show()
fig.savefig(fname='miami.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am kind of unsure on what you mean.

```
Say Df = 
A   B   low_confidence_variant
10  20    True
2    4    False
6    0    False

So after deleting the rows with low_confidence_variant = True, you should have
df = 
A   B     low_confidence_variant
2   4      False
6   0      False
```

Right?

If this is what you mean:

```
### Add below line
df = df[df['low_confidence_variant'] != True]
```

And delete this line

```
### Delete this line from the code
df.drop(['low_confidence_variant'], True)
```

What you are doing is to remove the whole column itself.